# Center align content inside a div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, center

Well, the tittle says it all. How can I center align those 3 thumbnails inside that div?
I've tried many solutions presented at SO and other places on the web but no success.

I'm not a professional in Bootstrap, webdesign or CSS but how can something so simple be so difficult?

[Check my problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54BaW.jpg)

My Bootstrap code:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="span3">
        <div class="mask3"> <a href="img/profile-01.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="img/profile-01.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
        <div class="inside">
        </div>
        <!-- /.inside -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.span3 -->
      <div class="span3">
        <div class="mask3"> <a href="img/profile-01.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="img/profile-01.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
        <div class="inside">
        </div>
        <!-- /.inside -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.span3 -->
     <div class="span3">
        <div class="mask3"> <a href="img/profile-01.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="img/profile-01.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
        <div class="inside">
        </div>
      <!-- /.inside -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.span3 -->
      </div>
```

My CSS section:

https://jsbin.com/pabebetoqo/edit?html,css,output

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? The span* classes have been replaced with col-sm-*

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/ the bootstrap docs

Comment: Oh and you can use the class center-block to center things or text-center

Answer (score 1):

You should study up a little bit on [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), which is a CSS technology invented for this sort of layout thing. It is actually really simple. I think the following might do the trick.

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: This was by far the quickest and easier solution! Just applied your suggestion to my css and puff... You made my day!

Comment: @Pumizo Glad to hear it, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Keep asking and answering questions! Remember also to vote on questions or answers that you find useful so they "float to the top" when others are looking for similar answers.

Comment: @Pumizo SO (Stack Overflow) has a really cool tour, too, if you're interested. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just center the row that contained the three elements via the [`text-align:center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) style?

```
/* This will center all of the content within your row */
.row { text-align: center; }
```

Or if you wanted to be more specific, just your `mask3` elements :

```
/* Likewise, this would center only the content in your mask3 elements */
.mask3{ text-align: center; }
```

**Example**

[image]

```css
/* History */

.mask3 {
  text-align: center;
}
section#history {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
section#history h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
section#history hgroup h2 {
  margin-top: 1em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
section#history hgroup h3 {
  margin-top: .35em;
  font-family: 'Patua One', cursive;
}
section#history .entry-content {
  margin: 1em 0 2.5em;
}
section#history .align {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 6em;
}
/* history Image Hover */

.mask3 img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.6;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.mask3 img:hover {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=99)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=99);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
      <div class="mask3">
        <a href="img/profile-01.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto">
          <img src="img/profile-01.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="inside">
      </div>
      <!-- /.inside -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.span3 -->
    <div class="span3">
      <div class="mask3">
        <a href="img/profile-01.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto">
          <img src="img/profile-01.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="inside">
      </div>
      <!-- /.inside -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.span3 -->
    <div class="span3">
      <div class="mask3">
        <a href="img/profile-01.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto">
          <img src="img/profile-01.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="inside">
      </div>
      <!-- /.inside -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.span3 -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the text align css

```
.mask3 {
   text-align: center;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

```
<div class="dogs-box">
    <img src="url" class="dog" />
    <img src="url" class="dog" />
    <img src="url" class="dog" />
</div>
```

And then set:

```
.dogs-box {
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}

.dog {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

I've created a very simple example which demonstrates exactly what you are trying to achieve: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w4bkf96o/5/)